# Zend Framework: How to 301 redirect old routes to new custom routes?

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a large list of old routes that I need to redirect to new routes.

I am already defining my custom routes in the Bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $oldRoute = 'old/route.html';
    $newRoute = 'new/route/*';

    //how do I add a 301 redirect to the new route?

    $router->addRoute('new_route', 
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route($newRoute,
            array('controller' =>'fancy', 'action' => 'route')
    ));
}
```

How can I add routes that redirect the old routes using a 301 redirect to the new routes?

Comment: Why sending 301 when doing no redirect? From what I can see you just do map the old routes to the new ones without redirect?

Comment: sorry, bad example. I am trying to redirect, not route.

Comment: I have updated the example to be more clear

Comment: You're still asking about routers - they have nothing to do with redirects and the (http) response. At the time you init routers you don't have any response object as the request isn't dispatched yet. So the only way to redirect there is with php's header function. But to be honest I don't understand your question. I guess you want the old urls/routes ('/new/route/1234') to be mapped to the new controller/actions? If that's the case you don't do any redirect yet. If it's already redirected  it's too late for a http-status code. Where does the actual redirect happen (code?)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zend Framework does not have this type of functionality built in. So I have created a custom Route object in order to handle this:

```
class Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Redirect extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route
{
    public function match($path, $partial = false)
    {
        if ($route = parent::match($path, $partial)) {
            $helper = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
            $helper->setCode(301);
            $helper->gotoRoute($route);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it when defining your routes:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initCustomRoutes()
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Redirect('old/route/*', array('controller'=>'content', 'action'=>'index'));       
        $router->addRoute('old_route', $route);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I've done it like this

1. Add a Zend_Route_Regexp route as the old route
2. Add Controller and action for the old route
3. Add logic to parse old route
4. Add `$this->_redirect($url, array('code' => 301))` for this logic

Comment: I think that's what I'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In controller, try this way:

```
     $this->getHelper('redirector')->setCode(301);
     $this->_redirect(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to solve this issue.

The **easiest** is probably to just use your `.htaccess` file to do a [`RewriteRule pattern substitution [R=301]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)

You could also detect what route was used in the controller and redirect based on that:

```
public function preDispatch() {
  $router = $this->getFrontController()->getRouter();
  if ($router->getCurrentRouteName() != 'default') {
    return $this->_redirect($url, array('code'=>301));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I used to do it was to redirect to a controller that only handled redirects. Now I use the custom class mentioned in my other answer.

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initRoutes()
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

        //new routes
        $router->addRoute('myroute', 
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('/new/route/1234',
                array('controller' =>'brands', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => '4')
        ));

        //old routes
        $oldRoutes = array(
            '/old/route/number/1' => '/new/route/1234',
        }
        foreach ($oldRoutes as $oldRoute => $newRoute) {
            $router->addRoute($oldRoute,  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static($oldRoute, array('controller' =>'old-routes', 'action' => 'redirect', 'new-route' => $newRoute)));
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
class OldRoutesController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{    
    public function redirectAction()
    {
        $newRoute = $this->_getParam('new-route');
        return $this->_redirect($newRoute, array('code' => 301));
    }
}
```