# how to change zend controller names gracefully

Tags: zend-framework, seo, routes

I currently have a broken site structure that needs repair and I want to do it without doing much damage to whatever little SEO we have currently.

```
What I have is .com/doctor/office/route/values/here
What I want is .com/doctors/route/values/here
```

I'm guessing I can just set up a "doctor" controller to redirect all traffic to a "doctors" controller, but I need to make sure that the route values come across properly.  I want to make sure it's a 301 to update all of my indexed pages.

Is there something built into Zend to do this easily?  Or am I going to have to hack something nasty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework: How to 301 redirect old routes to new custom routes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229204/zend-framework-how-to-301-redirect-old-routes-to-new-custom-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there are essentially two requirements:

1. Old urls get redirected to new urls.
2. New urls get handled by old controllers.

So:

1. Create a `DoctorRedirectController` with `redirectAction()`
2. Reroute the old urls to the `redirectAction()`. If you were using default routes before, then add a custom route that maps your old pattern to this new `redirectAction`. If you were already using custom routes, then just point them to this new redirect controller.
3. The `redirectAction()` builds the corresponding new url and does a 301-redirect.
4. Add routes that map the new urls to the old controller/actions.

No Zend magic, just the grunty work of remapping.