# Zend Framework Routing Forward

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an old url '/report/details/' and now I want to change this url to '/customer_report/details'. The controller name is reportController and the action is detailsAction.

I setup the routes.ini and added the following:

```
routes.report.route = /customer_report/details/
routes.report.defaults.controller = report
routes.report.defaults.action = details
```

After editing the routes.ini, if I use the url '/cutomer_report/details', it works perfectly. However, if I enter the url '/report/details/', it still works.

Is there any way that I can control whenever the url is /report/details, it will automatically redirect to /customer_report/details?

PS. I am using Zend Framework v1.12

Comment: The obvious answer is to refactor to rename the `report` controller to `customer_report`. When you achieve that you can remove the custom route.

Comment: A less obvious answer would be to add a controller plugin that listens to see if the old URL is being used and to either 404 it, or 300 redirect to the new route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to answer without information what ZF version you have. ZFv1 has predefined routes like `/:controller/:action` and that is why your `/report/details` route may still work. You can change this default behaviour clearing default routes:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$router->removeDefaultRoutes(); 
$router->addRoute(
   'error', 
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route (
       '/customer_report/details/',
       array (
          'controller' => 'report',
          'action' => 'details'
       )
    )
);
```

If you want to redirect users, you may move your logic to a new action:

```
public function customerReportAction() {
    // logic from reportAction()
}
```

and add http redirect in old one:

```
public function reportAction() {
   $this->_redirect('/customer_report/details/');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible to remove the default routes for this one only? cause I have other controllers and actions that use the default routes

Comment: Actually my question is not about removing the default routes. I sill want to keep /report/details usable, but in a different way. When /report/details is used, I want to redirect this to the '/cutomer_report/details' url.

Comment: In your report action, check the name of the matched route, and redirect if it's not `report`

Comment: Thanks @i.ovchynnikov  This works and just curious, do you have a better hacking solution as there are a lot of old urls that I have to change, and making lots of new controller modules will make the project more complicated.

Comment: @StanleyLi the most convenient solution is to create new routes that point to old ones.  But if you want a "redirection effect" on the client side, consider this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11416754/2180005